# Get Last Row of Different id then display data that is greater than zero

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is my table...

```
+----+--------+
| id | amount |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 1  | 50     |
| 1  | 0      |
| 2  | 500    |
| 2  | 100    |
| 3  | 300    |
| 3  | -2     |
| 4  | 400    |
| 4  | 200    |
+----+--------+
```

I would like to choose from it each value of `id` that does *not* have a nonpositive (i.e. negative or `0`) value associated with it, and the smallest `amount` associated with that `id`.

If I use this code...

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, amount 
FROM table t 
WHERE amount = (SELECT MIN(amount) FROM table WHERE id= t.id)
```

... then these results show...

```
+----+--------+
| id | amount |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 0      |
| 2  | 100    |
| 3  | -2     |
| 4  | 200    |
+----+--------+
```

But what I want the statement to return is...

```
+----+--------+
| id | amount |
+----+--------+
| 2  | 100    |
| 4  | 200    |
+----+--------+
```

Comment: What's the primary key of this table?Is there any other column like a date column or something in the table??

Comment: By 'last row`, do you mean the smallest value of `amount` for that `id`, the largest or the last that occurs in the unsorted list?

Comment: @JibinBalachandran no primary key. just the two column

Comment: @toonice yes the smallest value. but greater than zero

Comment: @elaine8s That's a very bad table structure.If it's in the initial stage of your development, better change the table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `amount>0` in your query. You missed out that condition in your query. That should do it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, amount FROM table t 
WHERE amount = (SELECT MIN(amount) FROM table WHERE id= t.id)
and amount>0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display id, where `min(amount)` > `0`, the use this.

```
SELECT id, min(amount) as amount
FROM table t 
group by id
having min(amount) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT id,
       MIN( amount )
FROM table
WHERE amount > 0
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

This statement starts by selecting all records `WHERE` `amount` is larger than `0`.

The records from the resulting dataset are then grouped by each surviving value of `id` and the smallest value of `amount` is chosen for that `GROUP` / `id`.

The resulting pairs of values are then sorted by `ORDER id` and returned to the user.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: No worries.  Glad to have tried to help.  Would you mind if I edited your question to clarify the problem description?