# Get Last Row or Smallest data then join two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

Using this Question where it is related [Get Last Row of Different id then display data that is greater than zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43861893/get-last-row-of-different-id-then-display-data-that-is-greater-than-zero)

I would like to join another table

This is my table2

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   | 
+----+--------+
| 1  | Taylor |
| 2  | Zac    |
| 3  | Scott  |
| 4  | Emma   |
+----+--------+
```

If I use this code...

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t1.amount, t2.name FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.amount = (SELECT MIN(t1.amount) FROM table1 WHERE id= t1.id) AND t1.[t1.amount]>0 AND t1.[id]=t2.[id];
```

... then these result show...

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id | amount | name  |
+----+--------+-------+
| 2  | 100    | Zac   |
+----+--------+-------+
```

only 1 data is showing

what i want is both data in the table

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id | amount | name  |
+----+--------+-------+
| 2  | 100    | Zac   |
| 4  | 200    | Emma  |
+----+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `t1.[t1.amount]` to just `t1.amount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id,t2.name,t.amount 
FROM table t
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t.id=t2.id 
WHERE amount = (SELECT MIN(amount) FROM table WHERE id= t.id)
and amount>0;
```

Comment: @elaine8s That should work, I guess there's no matching id in the second table. Try changing `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` and check.

Comment: thanks i tried LEFT JOIN and it works. thank you  for ur help :)

Answer (score 0):

Believe you're looking for a subquery of the first table, try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t1.amount, t2.name 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, amount FROM table t 
WHERE amount = (SELECT MIN(amount) FROM table WHERE id= t.id)
and amount>0) t1, table2 t2 
WHERE t1.[id]=t2.[id];
```

Not sure why your current query isn't working but hope this helps!

Comment: Very curious, and you can confirm that the query from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43861893/get-last-row-of-different-id-then-display-data-that-is-greater-than-zero is returning the two rows?

Comment: So something's failing on the join on t2.id then. Can you try:
select * from table2 where id in (2,4), does that give you the corresponding 2 records for table2?

Comment: but you're still not getting the name for id 4 when you should be based on the tables you posted...

Comment: i use the code suggested by Jimin and change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN. and i saw the data i want.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT table2.id AS id,
       minAmount AS amount,
       name
FROM ( SELECT id,
              MIN( amount ) AS minAmount
       FROM table1
       GROUP BY id
       HAVING MIN( amount ) > 0
     ) AS table1Refiner
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1Refiner.id = table2.id;
```

This statement works by obtaining the results as per your first Question and joining them to `table2` based on their shared values of `id`, effectively appending the corresponding `name` to each `id` and `amount`.  The fields are then selected and output.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Working answer developed, tested and posted.  Working on new explanation.

Comment: Updated explanation added.

Comment: thanks for helping. i already got the answer. i just change inner join to left join. thanks again. :)